# Why is <xsl:template match="*"> out competing more specific templates?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a complex collection of stylesheets meant to create a SQL insert statement from a variety of XML files. The XML files can come in a variety of schema. I have several templates for handling these schema, though I may receive XML which is not recognized. For this case, I have a default template that simply matches "*". I am finding that this default template *sometimes* takes precedence over more specific templates. **Moreover, when I comment out the default template, the more specific template matches successfully. Forcing priority doesn't help.** I'm running Saxon HE 9.6. This happens if I use 9.9 as well.

### Templates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="article/front"> <!-- loses to default -->
        <xsl:text>article/front matched</xsl:text>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="header"> <!-- wins against default -->
        <xsl:text>header matched</xsl:text>
       
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:text>DEFAULT MATCH</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't provide full XML, but here are some mock ups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE header SYSTEM "http://ej.slop.org/dtd/header.dtd">
<header>
  <notification type="new" timestamp="2020-02-27 00:59:35"/>
</header>
```

```
<article xml:lang="en" article-type="research-article" dtd-version="1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <front>
        <journal-meta>
            <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">CLM</journal-id>
        </journal-meta>
    </front>
</article>
```

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example that shows this: `<xsl:template match="book-part-wrapper"> <!-- loses to match="*" -->`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k OK I provided a full style sheet that behaves the same way as my original sheet does.

Comment: Your stylesheet has no template matching `book-part-wrapper`. It has  a template matching `header` - and it overrides the template matching `*`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZw

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes I used another template for article/front instead, which exhibits the same problem. The other XML mock up uses article/front

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example that shows this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tested it with Saxon-HE 9.9.1.4J and everything is working as expected.

1. In case of your first XML, the result is

   > header matched

   which is correct, because the `<xsl:template match="header">` rule matches the `<header>` root element. And end.
2. In case of your second XML, the result is

   > DEFAULT MATCH

   which is also correct, because it matches the root element `<article>` with the `<xsl:template match="*">` rule. And end. The rule `<xsl:template match="article/front">` does not apply, because it would only be applied on `<front>` elements which have an `<article>` parent. And there are no `<front>` elements in the template chain, because the `*` rule does not call `xsl:apply-templates`.

So everything is working correctly.

If you comment out the `<xsl:template match="*">` rule, the [built-in-template-rules](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/ch02s04s05.html) will apply. The relevant one here is

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This rule descends into the tree until another rule matches. Here it is `<xsl:template match="article/front">` which will give you the result

> article/front matched

with your second XML. The result of the first one stays the same.